# How to run Fuzzy Control Language

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I want to know about Fuzzy Control Language and then how could we use it inside Java application using jfuzzy library. 
How to run FCL file?
Regards

Comment: Have you seen [this paper?](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/pdf/Cingolani_Alcala-Fdez_jFuzzyLogic_2013_IJCIS.pdf)

Comment: Also, [this one](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/doc/iec_1131_7_cd1.pdf) I believe has helped me in the past.

Comment: @MattCremeens, I just had a glance on it.. I am reading it now in detail.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Keep me posted if you like. I implemented something similar to what I think you are trying to do and I may be able to show you some examples of my work. All the best.

Comment: @MattCremeens, thanks a lot. I need it please, kindly if you provide some examples?

Comment: OK. I'll try to write something up this weekend that will hopefully get you started.

Comment: @MattCremeens, its so kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back I wrote a system that would help triage patients based on the symptoms they were presenting in the emergency room. I'll present snippets of it here in the hopes that it will help get you started.

This all assumes that you have the jFuzzyLogic toolbox installed in the lib folder of your project.

You specifically ask about FCL files. I put these in my main project folder and one such file looks something like this

```
// Block definition (there may be more than one block per file)
FUNCTION_BLOCK back_pain
// Define input variables
VAR_INPUT
    airway : REAL;
    oxygenation : REAL;
    sweating: REAL;
    color: REAL;
    heart_rate: REAL;
    blood_pressure: REAL;
    conscious_level: REAL;
    abdominal_pain: REAL;
    pain: REAL;
    mechanism_of_injury: REAL;
    life_stage: REAL;
    direct_trauma: REAL;
    skin_temperature: REAL;
    neurological_deficit: REAL;
    unable_to_walk: REAL;
    colicky_pain: REAL;
    onset: REAL;
    untruthful_story: REAL;
    onset_of_symptoms: REAL;
END_VAR

// Define output variable
VAR_OUTPUT
    situation : REAL;
END_VAR

//Fuzzify input variables
FUZZIFY airway
    TERM not_maintained := 0; 
    TERM maintained := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY oxygenation
TERM inadequate := trape 0 0 21 36;
TERM adequate_but_very_low := trape 20 35 41 56;
TERM adequate_but_low := trape 40 55 61 76;
TERM adequate := trape 60 78 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY sweating
TERM little_to_none := trape 0 0 21 36;
TERM some := trape 20 35 41 56;
TERM significant := trape 40 55 61 76;
TERM exceptional := trape 60 75 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY color
TERM pale := trape 0 0 27 45;
TERM somewhat_lacking := trape 30 48 57 75;
TERM full := trape 60 78 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY heart_rate
TERM light := trape 0 0 21 36;
TERM moderate := trape 20 35 41 56;
TERM vigorous := trape 40 55 61 76;
TERM very_vigorous := trape 60 75 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY blood_pressure
TERM low := trape 0 0 27 45;
TERM normal := trape 30 48 57 75;
TERM high_normal := trape 60 78 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY conscious_level
TERM unresponsive := trape 0 0 21 36;
TERM reduced := trape 20 35 41 56;
TERM slightly_reduced := trape 40 55 61 76;
TERM normal := trape 60 75 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY life_stage
TERM infant := trape 0 0 21 31;
TERM toddler := trape 17 28 34 45;
TERM child := trape 32 44 50 62;
TERM adult := trape 60 70 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY mechanism_of_injury
TERM minor := trape 0 0 27 45;
TERM moderate := trape 56 77 80 101;
TERM significant := trape 60 81 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY pain
TERM little_to_none := trape 0 0 21 36;
TERM mild := trape 20 38 38 56;
TERM moderate := trape 40 58 58 76;
TERM severe := trape 60 78 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY abdominal_pain
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY direct_trauma
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY neurological_deficit
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY onset
TERM distant := trape 0 0 17 23;
TERM recent := trape 17 25 30 38;
TERM acute := trape 32 39 44 52;
TERM rapid := trape 43 49 54 60;
TERM abrupt := trape 60 73 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY unable_to_walk
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY skin_temperature
TERM cold := trape 0 0 15 30;
TERM normal := trape 24 34 45 55;
TERM warm := trape 39 49 60 70;
TERM hot := trape 53 65 70 83;
TERM very_hot := trape 60 72 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY untruthful_story
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY colicky_pain
    TERM not_present := 0;
    TERM present := 1;
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY onset_of_symptoms
TERM distant := trape 0 0 17 23;
TERM recent := trape 17 25 30 38;
TERM acute := trape 32 39 44 52;
TERM rapid := trape 43 49 54 60;
TERM abrupt := trape 60 73 100 100;
END_FUZZIFY

// Defuzzify output variable 'situation'
DEFUZZIFY situation
    TERM immediate := trape 0 0 2.5 5;
    TERM very_urgent := trian 3 6.5 10;
    TERM urgent := trian 8 34 60;
    TERM standard := trian 50 85 120;
    TERM non_urgent := trape 100 170 240 240;
    // Use 'Right-most Maximum' defuzzification method
    METHOD : RM;
    // Default value is 240 (if no rule activates defuzzifier)
    DEFAULT := 240;
END_DEFUZZIFY

RULEBLOCK No1
    // Use 'min' for 'and' (also implicit use 'max'
    // for 'or' to fulfill DeMorgan's Law)
    AND : MIN;
    // Use 'min' activation method
    ACT : MIN;
    // Use 'max' accumulation method
    ACCU : MAX;

    RULE 1 : IF airway IS NOT maintained 
                THEN situation IS immediate WITH 1.0;

    RULE 2 : IF oxygenation IS inadequate 
                THEN situation IS immediate WITH 1.0; 

    RULE 3 : IF (sweating IS significant OR sweating IS exceptional)
             AND (color IS pale)
             AND (heart_rate IS vigorous OR heart_rate IS very_vigorous)
             AND (blood_pressure IS low)
             AND (conscious_level IS reduced OR conscious_level IS unresponsive) 
                THEN situation IS immediate WITH 1.0;
    RULE 4 : IF pain IS severe
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 5 : IF mechanism_of_injury IS significant
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 6 : IF neurological_deficit IS present 
             AND (onset IS abrupt OR onset IS rapid OR onset IS acute)
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 7 : IF (life_stage IS infant OR life_stage IS toddler OR life_stage IS child)
             AND (skin_temperature IS hot OR skin_temperature IS very_hot)
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 8 : IF life_stage IS adult
             AND skin_temperature IS very_hot
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 9 : IF abdominal_pain IS present
                THEN situation IS very_urgent WITH 0.8;
    RULE 10 : IF neurological_deficit IS present
              AND onset IS recent
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 11 : IF untruthful_story IS present
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 12 : IF unable_to_walk IS present
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 13 : IF skin_temperature IS hot 
              AND life_stage IS adult
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 14 : IF pain IS moderate
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 15 : IF colicky_pain IS present
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;
    RULE 16 : IF direct_trauma IS present
                THEN situation IS urgent WITH 0.6;  
    RULE 17 : IF pain IS mild
                THEN situation IS standard WITH 0.4;
    RULE 18 : IF onset_of_symptoms IS recent
                THEN situation IS standard WITH 0.4;
END_RULEBLOCK

END_FUNCTION_BLOCK
```

This is where your fuzzy terms are defined, along with their membership functions (I used the trapezoidal membership function) and your fuzzy rules.

In my src folder I store java files that make use of such a FCL file. Here is one example

```
package com.project.triage;

import net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS;

/**
 * Test parsing an FCL file
 * @author pcingola@users.sourceforge.net
 */
public class FuzzyChestPain {
    double waitingTime;
    public FuzzyChestPain(boolean aw, int oxy, 
            int sweat, int col, int hr, int bp, int cl,
            int pain, boolean cardiac_pain, 
            boolean shortness_of_breath, 
            boolean irregular_rhythm, boolean pleuritic_pain,
            int history_of_cardiac, int onset_of_symptoms,
            int onset, int vomiting_no_blood) {
        // Load from 'FCL' file
        String fileName = "chest_pain.fcl";
        FIS fis = FIS.load(fileName,true);
        // Error while loading?
        if( fis == null ) { 
            System.err.println("Can't load file: '" 
                                   + fileName + "'");
            return;
        }

        // Show 
        //fis.chart();

        // Set inputs
        fis.setVariable("airway", convertBoolean(!aw));
        fis.setVariable("oxygenation", oxy);
        fis.setVariable("sweating", sweat);
        fis.setVariable("color", col);
        fis.setVariable("heart_rate", hr);
        fis.setVariable("blood_pressure", bp);
        fis.setVariable("conscious_level", cl);
        fis.setVariable("pain", pain);
        fis.setVariable("cardiac_pain", convertBoolean(cardiac_pain));
        fis.setVariable("shortness_of_breath", convertBoolean(shortness_of_breath));
        fis.setVariable("irregular_rhythm", convertBoolean(irregular_rhythm));
        fis.setVariable("pleuritic_pain", convertBoolean(pleuritic_pain));
        fis.setVariable("history_of_cardiac", history_of_cardiac);
        fis.setVariable("onset_of_symptoms", onset_of_symptoms);
        fis.setVariable("onset", onset);
        fis.setVariable("vomiting_no_blood", vomiting_no_blood);

       // Evaluate
        fis.evaluate();

        // Show output variable's chart 
        fis.getVariable("situation").chartDefuzzifier(true);
        //System.out.println("Patient should wait no longer than " + fis.getVariable("situation").getLatestDefuzzifiedValue());
        // Print ruleSet
        //System.out.println(fis);
        setWaitingTime(fis.getVariable("situation").getLatestDefuzzifiedValue());
    }

    private void setWaitingTime(double time) {
        waitingTime = time;
    }

    public double getWaitingTime() {
        return waitingTime;
    }



    //Convert boolean variables into 1s and 0s
    public int convertBoolean(boolean myVar) {
        if (myVar == true) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

A class like this one can be used to pass crisp inputs to your fuzzy variables and, in my case, defuzzify the output, time one can safely wait in an emergency room. You can see it's in this class that I load the FCL file that is shown above.

Hopefully this small example leads you in the right direction, but please feel free to ask if you have any questions. And Happy Easter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cooperation. I am reading it and will come back to you then. Thank you again and happy Easter.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question. We dont need to use fuzzy ontologies (Fuzzy Protege plugin) if we use jfuzzylogic? Problems like a person belongs to 0.8% to Young class and 0.2% to Old class, can be achieved efficiently using jfuzzy and FCL or we use fuzzy ontology and then use the traditional Jena and SPARQL to process it? Thank you

Comment: The example I gave just uses the jFuzzyLogic toolbox. That's it. I believe it will handle the example you gave.

Comment: My pleasure. I happen to enjoy this topic and it's nice to be able to discuss it again with someone. If I can help out, great.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I am busy in an assignment and then I will start to read and work on FCL and jFuzzyLogic and I will definitely need your support. Thank you again.

Comment: could you please guide me some (alternative) editors where we can write FCL code?

Comment: Mine was written using eclipse. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes thank you Matt. Netbeans will not work, right? The jfuzzy plugin used only in eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I do believe I was using Eclipse for the project discussed in this answer. All the best. Please do let me know how it all turns out. [Here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6893888/) is the paper that this work was used in.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I will let you know if there is problem.